# <UL> list item not being added in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So this is my props if I `console.log(this.props)`

```
list:Array(1):
{user: "Jack Nicholson", userid: "5b684ed8d3eb1972b6e04d32", socket: "1c0-Jb-kxe6kzPbPAAAD"}
```

However when I map through my `list` and use component `<UserItem user={user.user} />;` My UserItem keeps returning undefined.

```
render() {
    const UserItem = user => (
      <li>
        <div className="btn-group dropup">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            {user}
            {console.log(user)}
          </button>
          <div className="dropdown-menu" />
        </div>
      </li>
    );
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.list.map((user, i) => {
          console.log(this.props);
          <UserItem user={user.user} />;
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

Comment: what are you getting undefined?

Comment: try to change your "dummy" component to receive user prop like this `const UserItem = ({ user }) =>`

Comment: That's what I was assuming, but I tried that @JSEvgeny it still was undefined.

Comment: when using an arrow function with brackets, you need to explicitly `return`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow function in JS come in [two forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body): "concise body" and "block body". In concise form, as in your `const UserItem = user => (` function, the provided expression is implicitly returned.

However, in block form, as in your `this.props.list.map((user, i) => {` function, you must use an explicit `return` statement.

Try adding one to your code:

```
{this.props.list.map((user, i) => {
  console.log(this.props);
  return <UserItem user={user.user} />;
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the list as API response then handle the initial rendering also.However,return your `UserItem` component in the `map` function.try this code

```
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.list && this.props.list.map((user, i) => {
          console.log(this.props);
          return <UserItem user={user.user} />;
        })}
      </ul>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use round brackets instead of curly braces;

```
return (
  <ul>
    {
       this.props.list.map((user, i) => (
          <UserItem user={user.user} />
       ))
    }
  </ul>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `return` statement before `<UserItem user={user.user} />` ,also make sure to check if `this.props.list` exists before rendering it.

like so:

```
{this.props.list? this.props.list.map((user, i) => {
          console.log(this.props);
          return <UserItem user={user.user} />;
}):<span/>}
```